# Definition of soundness for interactive proof systems

Tags: interactive-proofs

I am reading the [Wikipedia page for Interactive proof systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_proof_system) and am having trouble understand the notation in the definition of soundness, many of which is left unspecified.

Given a formal language of strings $L$, a verifier $\mathcal{V}$ for this language satisfies the *soundness property* if for every prover $(\tilde{\mathcal{P}})$ and every $y \notin \mathcal{L}$,

$$ \operatorname{Pr}[(\bot,(\text{accept})) \leftarrow (\tilde{\mathcal{P}})(y) \leftrightarrow (\mathcal{V})(y)] < \epsilon $$

for some small $\epsilon \ll 1$. What is meant by the use of $\leftarrow$ and $\leftrightarrow$, as well as $(\bot,(\text{accept}))$? I would appreciate if someone could answer this or point me to a reference that uses (and defines) the same notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This notation is pretty common for interactive protocols (but it can vary from paper to paper). I believe:

- $\tilde{\mathcal{P}}(y)\leftrightarrow\mathcal{V}(y)$ denotes that $\tilde{\mathcal{P}}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ are interactive machines involved in an interactive protocol with common input the statement $y$ (an alternative is to use $\langle\tilde{\mathcal{P}},\mathcal{V}\rangle(y)$)
- $\leftarrow$ usually denotes the randomised output that results from this interaction (the verifier and the prover could use random coins)
- $\bot$ denotes that the (malicious) prover $\tilde{\mathcal{P}}$ has no (private) output at the end of the protocol (think of zero-knowledge protocols, e.g.)
- $\text{accept}$ denotes that the verifier accepts at the end of the protocol (again, think of zero-knowledge protocols)